# Give a specific predefined name when saving audio files in Android

Tags: android, file, save

How can I save a file to external storage with a predefined name for example like myfile_date.mp4?

Comment: Use Java file I/O. In other words, please be more specific about the nature of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For external storage we do something like this with basic intelligence..:

```
private String getFilename()
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYY").format(new Date());
        String MySound = "MySound";
        String DefinedName = MySound+timeStamp;


filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

if(!file.exists()){
    file.mkdirs();
}

return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DefinedName + file_exts[currentFormat]);
```

}